# create a trigger in oracle to avoid insertion on sunday

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I have employee table in oracle.I want to create a trigger that will avoid insertion of data on sun day. please tell me the program?following program not working.

Comment: following means what ? where is your code ?

Comment: Hello, please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example trigger that checks for week day and, if day is sunday (7), throws an user defined exception ORA-20000:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sunday
BEFORE INSERT ON employee
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') = '7' THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Cannot insert record on sunday'); 
    END IF;
END;
```

Please check which number identifies sunday, it depends on the local NLS settings of the database. Here in Italy (`NLS_TERRITORY='ITALY')` Sunday is identified by 7 but with different database NLS setting the number may vary. 
You may take a look at [Day of week (1-7) and NLS settings](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2207756)

Comment: This is again wrong.. 7 is not a sunday..as per oracle its 1. Please check my query.

Comment: 1 or 7 may be both right or wrong. It depends on the NLS settings of the database

Comment: So you must tell which NLS setting will give 7 as sunday as well.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger remains the same but the query goes like below:

to check whats day today"

```
select to_char(to_date('08/08/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DY'),TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') from dual;
```

To check next sunday:

```
select to_char(to_date('14/08/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DY'),TO_CHAR(to_date('14/08/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'D') from dual;
```

The correct code should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sunday
BEFORE INSERT ON employee
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') = '1' THEN   ---Should be 1 rather than 7
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Cannot insert record on sunday'); 
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: 1 or 7 may be both right or wrong. It depends on the NLS settings of the database

Comment: As most of the initial setting is of AMERICAN , so the above makes sense. Otherwise one has to modify his or her NLS setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your trigger as shown in below code snippet.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sunday_prevent
BEFORE INSERT ON account 
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
       IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'day')='sunday' then
               raise_application_error(-20000,'Today is Sunday so you not perform any transaction');
       END IF;
END;
/
```